# Where is @style/MyActionBarTitleText

Tags: android, xml, tags, android-actionbar

I’m new to android and are looking at tutorials to learn android development. I'm trying to figure out how all the xml files and tags are fit together.

In a google tutorial for actionbars one custom style, in themes.xml, look like this:

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>
```

I don't find or understand where "@style/MyActionBarTitleText" is defined and i don't get any compiling error in Eclipse. When a tag is referenced like this i thought it has to be defined in a xml file under my project somewhere but i cant find it?

Answer (score 0):

Style XMLs are defined in res/drawable[-mdpi/ldpi/xhdpi]

Style defines look of your Activity.  You can define color, themes, shapes in Styles.  Read more about styles and other resources here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html

Comment: In my project there are no files under res/drawable named style.xml or any other XML file containing element "MyActionBarTitleText".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can find it in: res->values->styles.xml

and also you can change your application theme/style in styles.xml file

Comment: I have looked in the styles.xml files and there is no XML element with the name "MyActionBarTitleText" defined.